# Determine current stable rust version

Tags: rust

Is it possible to find out the latest stable Rust version from inside a web page?  E.g. by getting some JSON or a text file from somewhere?

I note that the [rust forge](https://forge.rust-lang.org/) displays the current stable, beta and nightly versions.  That seems to be set by an mdbook preprocessor called blackjack and I was not able to see, quickly, where blackjack gets its data from.  Also, the stable version given there contains only the major and minor parts of the semantic version, excluding the patch number.

The GitHub API provides [the latest Rust release](https://api.github.com/repos/rust-lang/rust/releases/latest), however that does not correspond to the current stable version.  It is not even the newest Rust.  At the time of writing, the stable Rust is 1.72 but the latest GitHub release is 1.71.1.

Comment: Another avenue of enquiry might be to look at how rustup determines the latest versions.

Comment: Following @MaxMurphy comment, I'd guess it it this manifest: [`https://static.rust-lang.org/dist/channel-rust-stable.toml`](https://static.rust-lang.org/dist/channel-rust-stable.toml).

Comment: Thank you!  Yes, with some parsing this gives the desired answer on cli: `curl -sSL https://static.rust-lang.org/dist/channel-rust-stable.toml | yq -oy -p toml '.pkg.rust.target.x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.url' | sed -E 's!https://.*rust-([0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+).*!\1!g'`

Comment: Funny that there doesn't seem to be a rustup command that just emits the latest stable version. `rustup check | grep stable` is the nearest I can see.  But as long as that matches the url parsing method I can check that the output is correct.  Thanks again!

Comment: For the installed stable version I use `rustc +stable --version`, instead of querying `rustup`.

Comment: @MaxMurphy You should probably one or both of those as an answer. It'd still be valuable even if a better route comes along.